# Invalid revision: 3.18.1 CMake in Android Studio

Tags: android, cmake, version

This is not a question, it is a solution for a technical problem with android studio which I have meet. I will share my doing to fix the error if any one would encounter.
The brief error message is: **"Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901"**, while 3.18.1 is latest CMake version in Android studio. But the problem is my project is old and it builds failed with this CMake version. There are 2 solutions, you can choice 1 in 2:
-**Remove(uninstall) CMake** version 3.18.1: Click Android Studio->Preferences->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK->SDK Tool->(enable the Show Package Details checkbox)->CMake->Uncheck 3.18.1 checkbox, then click Apply button in right-bottom conner of dialog.
-**Set directory path** of lower-version CMake in the local.properties file by adding this line to this file: *`cmake.dir=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404`* *(The CMake path can be different in your computer)*

Long error message(a small part):

*

```
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901
    at com.android.repository.Revision.parseRevision(Revision.java:133)
    at com.android.repository.Revision.parseRevision(Revision.java:155)
    at com.android.build.gradle.external.cmake.CmakeUtils.getVersion(CmakeUtils.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.createCmakeExternalNativeJsonGenerator(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:688)
```

- 

Hope it help!

Comment: It's worth nothing that setting `cmake.dir` option to old version is buggy, and although silences OP's error causes new errors, like my Gradle did later call latest-cmake and ignored  `cmake.dir` option (untill I removed incompatible CMake-versions from Android-SDK's `cmake` directory).

Answer (score 37):

Downgrading `CMake` solves this issue (but it's a workaround).

1. `Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager`
2. Click `SDK Tools` tab
3. Check `Show Package Details`
4. Expand `CMake`
5. Select a lower version
6. Update `local.properties` path to the new version

[image: Downgrading CMAKE]

[image]

Comment: Downgrading shouldn't be a solution , but more of a work around.

Comment: Downgrading is definitely not a long-term solution as sooner or later Google will make it mandatory for us to use cmake 3.18 or things will start failing. I've experienced that with older NDK version. That said my project doesn't build with 3.18, because AS 4.1.3 re-download 3.10 automatically, what a mess :(

Comment: CMake 3.19.1 works. Presumably newer versions as well.

Comment: Another workaround is to replaces questionable cmake that returns pesky 3.18.1-g262b901-dirty version with real cmake.exe from cmake.org that report version just as 3.18.1.

Answer (score 4):

Gradle version | plugin-version
4.1.2          | 6.5

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade Gradle version and plugin-version to latest works for me

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my Gradle version to 4.1.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the following in the local.properties works for me.

```
ndk.dir=/Users/{USER}/Downloads/sdk/ndk/19.2.5345600
cmake.dir=/Users/{USER}/Downloads/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459
```