# Android project won't build due to dirty cmake version

Tags: android, cmake

I cannot build my project anymore. I always get this gradle sync issue:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901-dirty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

These are things I tried but did not resolve the issue:

- Reinstalled CMake version 3.18.1
- Tried [cleaning my cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313885/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbols-from-aar/50327343#50327343)

Also, I cannot use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540676/invalid-revision-3-18-1-cmake-in-android-studio) (which suggests downgrading my CMake version) because I got to use 3.18.1.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: No. I linked that too in my question.

Comment: When you create an empty project (and add some native code so cmake is used) does it compile?

Comment: can you please run with `--stacktrace` and `--debug` or `--scan` and show us the output? Right now it's not clear to me as someone who has little gradle experience and no android dev background that this has anything to do with CMake.

Comment: @zomega I created a brand new native project, i got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading my CMake version from 3.18.1 to 3.6.4111459 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540676/invalid-revision-3-18-1-cmake-in-android-studio). The only difference is that I did not have to add `cmake.dir` in my local.properties file.